# nicescroll jquery plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use nicescroll plugin. I added sources

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.iframehelper.min" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.min" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script>
```

I used some script suggested on this site like

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
$(window).load(function(){
$("body").css("overflow", "visible");        
var nice=$('html').niceScroll({cursorborder:"",cursorcolor:"#333333",cursorwidth:"8px", boxzoom:true, autohidemode:false});
});
</script>
```

or something like this

```
if (jQuery().niceScroll) {
    $("html").niceScroll({
        scrollspeed: 70,
        mousescrollstep: 38,
        cursorwidth: 15,
        cursorborder: 0,
        cursorcolor: '#0C090A',
        cursorborderradius: 0,
        autohidemode: true,
        horizrailenabled: false
    });
}
```

I tried some other scripts as well, but none of them remove standard scrollbar and change the overflow to hidden.

Comment: do proper code format

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: } see in last code @john2smitian

Comment: would someone please answer me

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing .js at the end of your file names? E.g. assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js